# How do you merge two NEAR Protocol accounts?

Tags: blockchain, nearprotocol

Say we create account `foo` on behalf of a user and give it some access keys, NFTs, and other good stuff.  Later, the user comes back with another NEAR account `bar` they have created in a different app which also has access keys, NFTs, tokens, etc.

What's the easiest way to merge `foo` and `bar` together with the least disruption to the user?

Comment: Please, define "merge" more specifically. Do you only need them to be able to manage "shared" assets on the contract you maintain? If so, it is up to the contract implementation. If you want to make it on the scale of the whole NEAR ecosystem, there is no such feature.

Comment: "Merge" here is more from the user perspective... if there was a single method that could effectively transfer all assets from one account to another and remove the original account.  The naive way is to identify all the assets and individually transfer them each according to their contracts but that seems very cumbersome at scale (esp if it requires individual approvals) so I hope there's something easier out there.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way at the moment is to transfer one asset at a time (as you suggested in the comment). You may also implement a small proxy contract and deploy it into the old account that will just echo actions it receives as a function call when it is executed by a trusted account id (new account), and this way new account id will be able to control assets of the old account id, but you will need to have custom tooling for that.

NEAR’s accounts model solved the problem for people needing to move all their assets if their access key leaked as assets are attached to an account id instead of a single access key (i.e. in other blockchains when your account id is 1:1 match to the access key you cannot add a new access key to the account and revoke the leaked key).